# Run an Excel macro from an Outlook macro?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

Greeting all,

Im working on a function where to run excel macro from outlook. my condition is to run the excel macro with the excel file is open and the outlook also open

my problem is. when i run this code. outlook will open another same excel file and ask for replace save.

what i want is, when i call the macro from the outlook. it will trigger the macro straight away from the open excel.

here is my code

```
    Sub macro()

Dim ExApp As Excel.Application

 Dim ExWbk As Workbook

 Set ExApp = New Excel.Application

 Set ExApp = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Production v2.7.1.xlsm")
 ExApp.Visible = True



 ExApp.Application.Run "'Production'!Main_function_Auto"

 ExApp.Close SaveChanges:=True



 End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Production`?

Comment: production is macro name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Sub macro()
    Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ExApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Not ExApp Is Nothing Then
        ExApp.Run "'C:\Users\Desktop\Production v2.7.1.xlsm'!Main_function_Auto"
    End If
End Sub
```